# Windows Forms: add new line to label if text is too long

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C#.  Sometimes the text returned from a web service (which I display in a label) is too long and gets cut off on the edge of the form.  Is there an easy way to add a newline to the label if it's not going to fit on the form?

Thanks

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-label-in-winforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do text formating in C# for adjusting text in some control.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117766/how-to-do-text-formating-in-c-for-adjusting-text-in-some-control)

Comment: Yeah... the "text formatting in C# for adjusting text" post did it.  I didn't see that when I searched around.  Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you set the label to `autosize`, it will automatically grow with whatever text you put in it.

In order to make it word wrap at a particular width, you can set the MaximumSize property.

```
myLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0);
myLabel.AutoSize = true;
```

Tested and works.

If you always want to be able to see the data, you can set the Label's container's `AutoScroll` property to true.

Comment: +1, winner.  Showing how to grow the form is what the OP forgot to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If the label control fails you, you can use a scrollable textbox instead.